# Code sniffer, How to validate just clear PSR2?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

my configuration:

`phpcs --config-set default_standard PSR2`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="test">
    <file>./../../web</file>

    <arg name="standard" value="PSR2"/>
    <arg name="extensions" value="php"/>
    <arg name="basepath" value="./../../"/>
    <arg name="tab-width" value="4"/>

    <rule ref="PSR2">
        <exclude name="Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowTabIndent"/>
        <exclude name="Generic.Files.LineLength.TooLong"/>
    </rule>

    <rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowSpaceIndent"/>

    <rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent">
        <properties>
            <property name="indent" value="4"/>
            <property name="tabIndent" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

In report I have `PSR1`, `PSR2`, `Generic` and `Squiz` rules

How can I validate only clear `PSR2` without `Generic` and `Squiz`?

And second things: where can I found standard documentation for `Generic` and `Squiz`?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The PSR2 standard uses sniffs from other standards to enforce its rules. This is because there is a lot of overlap between standards and it doesn't make sense to duplicate the code. So the PSR2 standard pulls in checks from other standards to enforce similar rules.

When you tell PHP_CodeSniffer to check files using the PSR2 standard, you can be sure that it is only enforcing the PSR2 rules no matter what sniffs are being used to enforce it.